# Using `ls` recursively without -R

Tags: shell-script, ls, recursive

I am trying write a shell script that has output similar to `ls -R` without using the option `-R`.

This is part of a programming assignment that forbids me from using `-R`, `find` and `du`. I need to identify the top 5 files/directories inside my entire home directory and to say how many directories and files there are in total.

I understand that I can use  `{sort -n | tail -n}` to get the top 5 files but I can't work out how to get an unfiltered list of all files and directories recursively without using the option `-R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're being asked to write a recursive script yourself rather than relying on a command that does the recursion for you.

Here's the skeleton of such a function. I've left some of the parts blank for you to fill out.

```
listAllFiles() {
    local dir=$1
    local file

    for file in "$dir"/*; do
        if <$file is a directory>; then
            listAllFiles "$file"
        else
            <print $file>
        fi
    done
}
```

At a high level, this function takes a directory as its first argument. It loops over the contents of that directory. If it finds a sub-directory, it calls itself. Otherwise it prints what it found. This will end up recursing through a directory structure.

You can use this function the same way you'd use a built-in command like `ls -R` or `find`. You could store the results in a variable:

```
allFilesInCurrentDirectory=$(listAllFiles .)
```

Or you could use it in a pipeline:

```
listAllFiles ~/ | cmd1 | cmd2
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify bash explicitly so I'm taking the freedom to offer you a very simple solution for zsh:

```
ls -d ~/**/*| egrep -v "/.*/.*/.*/"
```

If you want to include dot files as well:

```
ls -d ~/**/*(D)| egrep -v "/.*/.*/.*/"
```

These only assume that you do not have zillions of files in your home! If you do, you will get an argument list too long error. But you may run into similar errors with any solution that gives an answer in one step. (Recursive function calls too).